# Why does select from sqlite db shows error 'Specified cast is not valid.' in Xamarin Forms?

Tags: c#, sqlite, xamarin.forms

Getting a single value from by SQLite database but I get the error System.InvalidCastException: 'Specified cast is not valid.'
I need only the first value of the select results, tried both First() and ElementAtOrDefault(0) but same thing happens.

Error gets catched when trying to assing to the variable IDPromoMainPage, not before.

Basically this is how I call the value:

```
private void GetPromoLocal()
        {
            try
            {
                var databasePath = System.IO.Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal), "LocalDB.db3");
                var db = new SQLiteConnection(databasePath);
                IEnumerable<T_Promo> resultado = SELECT_WHERE(db);
                if (resultado.Count() > 0)
                {
                    IDPromoMainPage = Convert.ToInt32(resultado.First()); // ElementAtOrDefault(0));
                }
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                throw;
            }
        }
        public static IEnumerable<T_Promo> SELECT_WHERE(SQLiteConnection db)
        {
            return db.Query<T_Promo>("SELECT IDPromo FROM T_Promo");
        }
```

Also have the same error happening here, exactly at line "PisterosLista = resultado.Cast().ToList();"

```
List<Pisteros> PisterosLista = new List<Pisteros>();

public void GetPisterosLocal()
        {
            try
            {
                var databasePath = System.IO.Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal), "LocalDB.db3");
                var db = new SQLiteConnection(databasePath);
                IEnumerable<T_Pisteros> resultado = SELECT_WHERE_Pist(db);
                if (resultado.Count() > 0)
                {
                    PisterosLista = resultado.Cast<Pisteros>().ToList();
                    //Console.WriteLine("content :: " + content);
                    Console.WriteLine("Data :: " + PisterosLista);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                throw;
            }
        }
        public static IEnumerable<T_Pisteros> SELECT_WHERE_Pist(SQLiteConnection db)
        {
            return db.Query<T_Pisteros>("SELECT * FROM T_Pisteros");
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if the column `IDPromo` is an int, then just do this

```
    IEnumerable<int> resultado = SELECT_WHERE(db);

    public static IEnumerable<int> SELECT_WHERE(SQLiteConnection db)
    {
        return db.Query<int>("SELECT IDPromo FROM T_Promo");
    }
```

Comment: Doesn't work, doesn't even get data back from the DB, even though yes, IDPromo field is integer

Comment: First time was an exception, now I tried again and worked. But I'm using IDPromoMainPage = resultado.First(); to assign the value and always returns 0, when the value should be 1.

Comment: I would check your data to be sure that’s the case.  And that query is not guaranteed to be sorted in any particular order

Comment: There should only exists 1 row, so the sort thing is not an issue.
When inserting the data I'm using
```
 private SQLiteAsyncConnection _conn; 
_conn.InsertAsync(DatosRegistro); 
```


and for this query I'm using 
```
var databasePath = System.IO.Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal), "LocalDB.db3");
                var db = new SQLiteConnection(databasePath);
```

but I don't know if that's ok

Comment: Is DatosRegistro of type T_promo?

Comment: yeah

var DatosRegistro = new T_Promo
            {
                IDPromo = IDPromoMainPage
            };